# Insert Javascript code inside img src

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to insert Javascript code to a src tag from an img, the code looks like:

```html
<img id="p1" width="90%" height="100%" src="javascript:img_info();" />
```

So basically it gets an image out of an API since the function `img_info();` generates a link. The problem is that when i run this code it doesn't return anything, any ideas?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452233/set-image-src-to-an-img-element-with-function-return-in-javascript) provides reasonable solutions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry, `javascript:` is not aviable for the `src` attribute. And `src="img_info()"` is not possible as well.

---

This is how you can do it:

```
<img id="p1" width="90%" height="100%" src="" />
<script>document.getElementById("p1").src = img_info()</script>
```

---

*Note that `onload` won't trigger with an empty `src=""` attribute! `<img onload="this.src = img_info()" />` wont't work*.

---

Live Example:

```html
<script>
  function img_info() {
    return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Faust_bei_der_Arbeit.JPG"
  }
</script>


<img id="p1" width="90%" height="100%" src="" />
<script>
  document.getElementById("p1").src = img_info()
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can put in a errant SRC and use the onload event if you prefer to keep it all within a tag.

```
<img src="bogus.url" onError="initImage(this)">
```

Answer (score -1):

Put it in an `onload` event instead and set the `src` with `setAttribute`.

So something like

```
<img onload="this.setAttribute('src', img_info())" >
```

Comment: As it was pointed in the chosen answer, this won't work, because onload event will not trigger before a src has being defined.